# 3D vape bottle renders and other 3D elements

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I am looking for information on what software to use to create renders like these. I specifically refer to the Bottle and liquid.

I have seen a few bottles done in different angles and I think they look fantastic! I also want to be able to create this shape of bottle and cap in said program. The bottle in this image may look like a photograph but there are renders that can be done like this.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Current Status after member responses:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try Blender. It's free and open source, and cross platform. There are [tutorials on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+tutorial+bottle+and+cap). There's even a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi Billy,
Thank you for the recommendation! I most certainly will check it out

Comment: The bottle is possible with general CAD programs which have photorealistic materials and texture mapping; it's possible to draw it even with Illustrator, but the liquid needs something really powerful. As said already, try Blender. Prepare to work weeks to get over the basics. The liquid needs physics simulation and that's useless to try before simpler tasks are handled reliably.

Comment: for now my goal is just to create the bottle and have the ability to add a label and have it rotate to any angle I need. I can see a huge learning curve here so I will do manipulations for liquids etc in Photoshop. The bigger stress I guess right now is getting the bottle done with the ability to rotate it as needed. This should in turn keep the label quality in check etc. I hope I am explaining properly, don't often do well in that department.

Comment: @Sash - yes, there is a steep learning curve with Blender, and all similarly powerful 3D modelling applications.

Comment: If you are in a hurry, might be worthwhile checking one of those 3D object stock libraries out there. [This one](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-bottle-120ml-model-1285845) has a model available as an .OBJ which is compatible with Blender.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for pointing me to that file!! Saves me hours (or who knows how long) of work! With this I can at least have an already working piece and can learn from there. I appreciate it very much!

Comment: I am the one that created that image, Hit me up anytime for help. @VapeRender Facebook or Vaperender.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am compelled to post this.

Now, in 2020 I would not use commercial software for this unless you are in a specific pipeline (with some VFX studio) or have a specific feature you need that is not included in Blender, and I must say they are very rare.

Let's take a look at some good examples.

First of all, Blender has a built-in fluid simulator, smoke simulator, photorealistic render, real-time render, sculpting tools, physics, particles... and it's free, (but not cheap).

Stills

Take a look at a general gallery: https://blenderartists.org/tags/featured

Video

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cycles+demo+reel

Some specific for fluids.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+fluid+simulation+2.8

https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-realistic-fruit-splash

And it has a community here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

---

I must add something. You can make a lot of things with the built-in fluid simulator. But if you want to spend some bucks take [a look at add on](https://blendermarket.com/products/flipfluids) which makes additional things, like the foam formed when a fluid is agitated and smaller particles. The difference is the scale.

With the internal simulator, you can easily make the scale you have on your image, let's say the splash made with a bucket. With the add on it simulates the scale of a tsunami.

Comment: thanks man some of this stuff is crazy! I do aim to learn Blender because I can see from what's being shared on it its abilities are just next level. I will get there though one day in the future. There is so much going on in my head right now. First I wanted to just do a still image but after all the info being shared with me on this post I am imaging doing something animated etc! I know I am very far away from those skills but I am just so mind blown right now!


ADD: OK, I'll give in. I'll import the object file that I bought of the bottle into Blender & see what I can fool around with!

Comment: I must say. There are a lot of programs with impressive demos. The diference is that blender is free and all included. Go right now and download it.

Comment: I have it installed yesterday and have been using since your comment. I have been battling to simply get the label to apply to the bottle. Watched videos on it as well but looks like I am just not grasping what to do. Back to Dimension I got for the moment!

Comment: Try to be specific on your searches: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=label+on+bottle+Blender&atb=v147-1&ia=web

Comment: Learning any 3D program is not an easy task. They require much more atention than any other software.

Answer (score 0):

You've already been pointed in comments to one **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tool -  [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), which is an amazingly powerful and feature rich program, especially given that it's both open-source and freeware. It's a great choice.

I'm going to point out there are dozens of such **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tools out there, and one often used in the packing design industry is one ***I myself*** use a lot - [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo).

There are both already in-built tools (see video link below) dedicated to that kind of design need, and even some package-design specific expansions to [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) which make it a super-efficient and effective tool for this kind of task - see [**PACK**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo/addons/package-design) kit.

Note that as is the case with most / many **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tools, they offer a 30-day free trial - and there are no watermarks or anything annoying like that - it just works.

[YouTube showing Modo native package design workflows - no add-ons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbDinIAzwxg)

Here's a render from one of my experiments some years ago with Modo and glass and liquids - everything modeled and textured and lit by me - no add-ons or pre-made content at all.

[image]

And this is a more recent model in the style of a well-known building toy whose name we shan't mention...
[image]

For my workflows and way of thinking, I find that [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) is the way to go - that said, as I said initially - [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/) is an excellent choice for any general 3D tasks.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks a mill Gerard! That video really helped me understand the price tag.
Modo looks like a super cool program and looks like its abilities are quite superior! Your works above are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Simple 3D programs do not have photorealistic materials nor rendering. They cannot for ex. handle glass transparency, light refraction nor metallic glosses.

Illustrator's 3D is even more limited. You can have only extruded or revolved shapes, the grooves in the cap of your bottle is unreachable in Illustrator.

If you can accept non-photorealistic shading and limited control on light and camera placements, you can use some entry level CAD program to create the geometry. The rendering result unfortunately will be quite plastic. Placing images on surfaces is the only way to get something else.

The next example has one elementary attempt to make the bottle from scratch in such entry level CAD program.  A GDSE screenshot is used as the label. There's 3 differently rotated copies of the same bottle:

[image]

The program is DesignSpark Mechanical (Win 64bit). It's free and so simple that one can be productive in days instead of weeks or months. It has SpaceClaim under the hood, but with quite reduced geometry creation options. That's common with free versions of commercial programs. But it's still much more flexible than Illustrator's 3D.

Sometimes there's a need to place a photo of an existing bottle to an image composition. It's tricky but it's surely useful to know something of it, too. Placing a new label is as necessary. See these, if you are interested:

[Photoshop: How to make shadow more realistic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/106014/photoshop-how-to-make-shadow-more-realistic)

[How do I wrap a label around a bottle](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125110/how-do-i-wrap-a-label-around-a-bottle)

ADD: You have seemingly already got something. Tilted bottle with horizontal liquid surface in 3D needs the liquid inside the bottle. You have got another answer which shows how well high end 3D modelling can make it.  A simpler approach is to insert inside the bottle a transparent solid piece which fills the same space that the liquid would take. To make it seem plausible one must have photorealistic materials and rendering which take optical effects refraction and reflection properly into the account. Here's an example with my simple non-photorealistic CAD program:

[image]

The green part is a revolution shape sliced to 2 pieces with a 30 degrees tilted temporary plane. The revolved sketch was the same which was used to make the hollow bottle interior, but scaled to 0,5% bigger size to be sure that there's no random gaps caused by rounding errors when the green part is placed inside the bottle.

In the next image the cap is again visible, the yellow ring is colored to grey, the green fill is placed, the composition is tilted 30 degrees and the bottle body is made 50% transparent:

[image]

As you see it's not at all plausible due the lack of photorealistic materials and rendering. Transparency without optical effects doesn't make it glass.

Comment: I have got to say that help this community has offered (especially to someone who has just joined) is outstanding! Thank you for giving me more resources & once I have completed my "scene" or what I am trying to achieve I will post it here so that you guys can also see that all these responses have not gone to waste. The resource @Billy Kerr has pointed me to has also helped me a lot along this journey. It also gets me thinking about the possibility of doing a very basic animation (like make the bottle spin) for the end result. Thank you for the time & response, these will help a great deal!

Comment: As an example, I will add an image to my OP as to where I am at, at the moment (not sure how to add it to this comment). I still need to figure out how to edit the liquid and make it slant inside the bottle. For now, I am doing this on Adobe Dimension as I found it easier to use than Blender. Blender seems very powerful and I think I will need a lot of time to learn that.

Comment: Super cool! Thank you for the idea on this. With what I have I can now at least fiddle a bit more and have an idea of what I should get to. This stuff has got me staring down a deep hole as it is a totally new style of design to me and I guess this is what I needed in my career :D

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So what did you end up doing for this project?  I think you'd be better off using stock images of liquid?  Maybe find a freelancer to create it for you in 3d?  How does the final result look?

Comment: Welcome to graphics.stackexchange but this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry I had abandoned it and it became a skeleton in my closet :-(